# Android filechooser not showing all folders/files but showing some

Tags: java, android

Why filechooser is not showing all (folders and files), but showing some files/folders ?

Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

FileChooser class:

```
public class FileChooser extends ListActivity {
    private File directory;
    private FileArrayAdapter adapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        directory = new File("/sdcard/");
        fill(directory);
    }

    public void fill(File f){
        File[] dirs = f.listFiles();
        this.setTitle("Dir:"+f.getName());
        List<Option> dir = new ArrayList<Option>();
        List<Option> files = new ArrayList<Option>();
        try{
            for(File ff:dirs){
                if(ff.isDirectory()){
                    dir.add(new Option(ff.getName(),"[+]Pasta ",ff.getPath()));
                }else{
                    long size;
                    if(ff.length()>0){
                        size=ff.length()/1024;
                    }else{
                        size=ff.length();
                    }
                    files.add(new Option(ff.getName(),"Tamanho "+size+"kb",ff.getPath()));
                }

            }
        }catch (Exception e){}
        Collections.sort(dir);
        Collections.sort(files);
        dir.addAll(files);


        if(!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            dir.add(0,new Option("..","pasta anterior",f.getParent()));
        }


        adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(FileChooser.this,R.layout.activity_file_chooser,dir);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(listView,view,position,id);
        Option o = adapter.getItems(position);

        if(o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("[+]Pasta ")||o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("pasta anterior")){
            directory = new File((o.getPath()));
            fill(directory);
        }else{
            try {
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                String classname = extras.getString("class");
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(classname);
                Intent intent = new Intent(FileChooser.this, clazz);
                intent.putExtra("path", o.getPath());
                startActivity(intent);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(">>>>", String.valueOf(e));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SDFOLDER on Emulator

With filebrowser apk

[image]

SDFOLDER or /Storage/Emulated/ on Emulator(Empty)

With my apk

[image: empty]

/sys/kernel/ on Emulator

With my apk (Working fine!)

[image: working]

Comment: Did you request runtime permission for read external storage? You are on 6.0. The user of your app can go to Settings too and switch the permission on. Did you?

Comment: Thanks! runtime permission worked fine!